# Getting last 5 elements of a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I get the last 5 elements of a PHP array?

My array is dynamically generated by a MySQL query result. The length is not fixed. If the length is smaller or equal to 5, then get all, else the last 5.

I tried the PHP functions `last()` and `array_pop()` but they return only the last element.

Comment: Please show, in code, the dynamically generated array that has no length.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), which does exactly this.

```
$items = array_slice($items, -5);
```

`-5` means "start at five elements before the end of the array".

Comment: What would be the behavior if `$items` only had, say, 3 elements?

Comment: @xbonez It would return those three elements. The manual doesn't say so, but that's what happens.

Comment: @Teez In what way is it not working? I'm not sure what a dynamic array is, but this should work on any array...

Comment: @lonesomeday: Gotcha. I was wondering if it would wrap around, and begin counting from the end of the array again...lol. That would be evil.

Comment: @Teez: You seem to be confused. If you call the slice method after populating the array, it will work.

Answer (score 6):

[`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)`($array, -5)` should do the trick

Answer (score 5):

`array_pop()` 5 times in a loop? If the returned value is a `null`, you've exhausted the array.

```
$lastFive = array();

for($i=0;$i < 5;$i++)
{
    $obj = array_pop($yourArray);

    if ($obj == null) break;
    $lastFive[] = $obj;
}
```

After seeing the other answers, I have to admit `array_slice()` looks shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to extend the question a little bit. What if you looping though a big file and want to keep the last 5 lines or 5 elements from a current position. And you don't want to keep huge array in a memory and having problems with the performance of array_slice.

This is a class that implements ArrayAccess interface.

It gets array and desired buffer limit.

You can work with the class object like it's an array but it will automatically keep ONLY last 5 elements

```
<?php
class MyBuffer implements ArrayAccess {
    private $container;
    private $limit;

    function __construct($myArray = array(), $limit = 5){
        $this->container = $myArray;
        $this->limit = $limit;
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
        $this->adjust();
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
    public function __get($offset){
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
    private function adjust(){
        if(count($this->container) == $this->limit+1){
            $this->container = array_slice($this->container, 1,$this->limit);
        }
    }
}


$buf = new MyBuffer();
$buf[]=1;
$buf[]=2;
$buf[]=3;
$buf[]=4;
$buf[]=5;
$buf[]=6;

echo print_r($buf, true);

$buf[]=7;
echo print_r($buf, true);


echo "\n";
echo $buf[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.phpoutpur)   and `count()`

```
$arraylength=count($array);

    if($arraylength >5)
         $output_array= array_slice($array,($arraylength-5),$arraylength);
    else
        $output_array=$array;
```