# Get last items in foreach php

Tags: php, magento, collections, foreach, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting last 5 elements of a php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704983/getting-last-5-elements-of-a-php-array)

Hi i have **around** 11000 **items** in an array and i want to **display** only **last** 5 or 10 **items**

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($collection as $product_all) { 
 if($i==2) break;    
 echo $product_all->getId();        
   $neew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_all->getId());         
echo'<pre>';
    print_r($neew); 
$i++; 
}
```

with this i got **first** 2 items , how can i get last  items only

Comment: See this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704983/getting-last-5-elements-of-a-php-array

Comment: philipbrown, if it is an array, not an iterator - still, a likely assumption ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is Magento, `$collection` is not an array but an Iterator. This means array functions like `array_slice` do not work, but you can simulate a foreach in reverse order like that:

```
end($collection);
while($current = current($collection)) {
    // ... (see below)
    prev($collection);
}
```

Inside the loop you would construct your array of the last 5 items and break after you have them:

```
$lastFive[] = $current;
if (count($lastFive) == 5) break;
```

Edit: Now that we have solved your immediate problem, let's talk about performance. It is a very bad idea to fetch 11000 items from the database into memory, just to use 5 or 10 of them. You should locate the code where `$collection` gets loaded and begin there. It is most likely something like:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->setOrder('id', 'asc')->load();
```

That could be changed to (reverse ORDER, add LIMIT):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->setOrder('id', 'desc')->setPageSize(5)->load();
```

Voilà, only the last 5 items get loaded.

Even better, your code looks like you only need the ids, not the actual models, so the whole thing could be optimized to:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$ids = $collection->setOrder('id', 'desc')->setPageSize(5)->getAllIds();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    // do what you want
}
```

Comment: if its not array then why he wrote foreach ($collection as $product_all)....he clearly said he has "around 11000 items in an array"..

Comment: Because he didn't know better. Iterators disguise themselves quite effectively as array.

Comment: @DipeshParmar, $collection is Magento's collection object. It couldn't be sliced like an array.

Comment: +1 for enenen don't know more about magento but definitely helpful to other...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

```
$items = array_slice($items, -5);
```

Comment: does not work in Magento as it was tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) php function.

If you want to preserve key, you can pass in true as the fourth argument:

```
array_slice($a, -5, 5, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$last = array_slice($collection, -5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code example...

```
$i = 0;
$no = count($collection);
foreach ($collection as $product_all) { 
 if($i >= ($no-10)) {
     echo $product_all->getId();        
     $neew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_all->getId());         
     echo'<pre>';
     print_r($neew); 
  }
  $i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want last `X` items:

```
$i = 0;
$totalCount = count($collection);
$itemsCount = 5; 
$x = $totalCount - $itemsCount;

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
    if ($i < $x) {
        $i++;
        continue;
    }
    echo $product_all->getId();
    $neew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_all->getId());
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($neew);
    $i++;
}
```

If you want only the last one you can use:

```
$lastItem = $collection->getLastItem();
```

But best solution is sorting and limiting your collection according to me. Why fetching 11000+ products (!) if you want to use only 5 or 10 from them? If you get the products without any sorting then they are ordered by `created_at` attribute as I remember. You can simply sort in descending order and limit to `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$array  = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

function foreach_last($array, $n, $func) {
    reset($array);
    end($array);
    $i  = 0;
    $n  = min($n, count($array)) - 1;
    while ( $i ++ < $n ) 
        prev($array);
    $func(current($array), key($array));
    while ( $v = next($array) ) {
        $func($v, key($array));
    }
}
function print_e($v, $k) {
    printf("k: %s, v: %s\n", $k, $v);
}

foreach_last($array, 5, 'print_e');
```